# Jasmine custom matcher with Protractor for checking browser title

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

I am writing a Jasmine custom matcher to use in a Protractor spec and I want to check that the browser title is equal to some string. I am unable to get this code to work properly and after spending hours debugging it, I can only assume that the `browser` object is not being accessed inside the matcher function as I expect it to be. When I modify the matcher function to accept `browse.getTitle()` as the actual argument then it works fine, which leads me to my assumption. Can anyone find the issue here and explain it to me?

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toBeOnPage: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    var result = {};
                    result.pass = actual.getTitle() === expected.title;
                    return result;
                }
            };
        }
    });
});

var homepage = { url: 'Homepage URL', title: 'Homepage Title' };

describe('regression:', function() {
    it('homepage loads successfully', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost/#/home');
        expect(browser).toBeOnPage(homepage);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`getTitle()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getTitle) *returns a promise*. Resolve it:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toBeOnPage: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
            return {
                compare: function(actual, expected) {
                    return {
                         pass: actual.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                              return title === expected.title;
                         });
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the fix.